# Pandas: split column of lists of unequal length into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like the below:

```
                   codes
1                  [71020]
2                  [77085]
3                  [36415]
4                  [99213, 99287]
5                  [99233, 99233, 99233]
```

I'm trying to split the lists in `df['codes']` into columns, like the below:

```
                   code_1      code_2      code_3   
1                  71020
2                  77085
3                  36415
4                  99213       99287
5                  99233       99233       99233
```

where columns that don't have a value (because the list was not that long) are filled with blanks or NaNs or something.

I've seen answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns) and others similar to it, and while they work on lists of equal length, they all throw errors when I try to use the methods on lists of unequal length. Is there a good way do to this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.codes.values.tolist()).add_prefix('code_')

   code_0   code_1   code_2
0   71020      NaN      NaN
1   77085      NaN      NaN
2   36415      NaN      NaN
3   99213  99287.0      NaN
4   99233  99233.0  99233.0
```

---

Include the `index`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.codes.values.tolist(), df.index).add_prefix('code_')

   code_0   code_1   code_2
1   71020      NaN      NaN
2   77085      NaN      NaN
3   36415      NaN      NaN
4   99213  99287.0      NaN
5   99233  99233.0  99233.0
```

---

We can nail down all the formatting with this:

```
f = lambda x: 'code_{}'.format(x + 1)
pd.DataFrame(
    df.codes.values.tolist(),
    df.index, dtype=object
).fillna('').rename(columns=f)

   code_1 code_2 code_3
1   71020              
2   77085              
3   36415              
4   99213  99287       
5   99233  99233  99233
```

Comment: If I have a column to keep. Is there any way to do it rather than merging back after spliting?

Comment: This works well as long as the first rows in the selected columns are not empty.  If they are empty then the list will not effectively split.  A work around is to dropna, keep the indexes as shown above and then rejoin on the initial dataframe.

Comment: @pendletonian - do you have a solution showing the use of `dropna`? I'm facing this problem at the moment.

Answer (score 20):

Another solution:

```
In [95]: df.codes.apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('code_')
Out[95]:
    code_0   code_1   code_2
1  71020.0      NaN      NaN
2  77085.0      NaN      NaN
3  36415.0      NaN      NaN
4  99213.0  99287.0      NaN
5  99233.0  99233.0  99233.0
```

Comment: This solution works best for me as it's able to handle a series that occasionally has empty lists

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function using @piRSquared solution that unrolls a dataframe from 3d (row x column x list of values) to 2d (row x column_{n})

```
def unroll_dataframe_columns_of_lists_to_columns(df):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for col in df.columns:
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, pd.DataFrame(df[col].values.tolist()).add_prefix(col + '_')], axis=1)
    new_df.index = df.index
    return new_df
```