# Pandas Dataframe : Assigning conditional values to each dataframe row on values greater than or lower than

Tags: python, dataframe

Currently i have dataframe which has has stock ticker and return

```
ticker_name    return
"AAPL 2020"    -15%
"AAPL 2019"     20%
"AAPL 2018"     40%
"AAPL 2017"     30%
"AAPL 2016"    -10%
....
```

I also have the data of index return in yearly format for the last x years.With this data want to tag if specific stock have above market return

```
sp_500_year return
"2020"      -30%
"2019"       10%
"2018"       10%
"2017"       10%
"2016"       20%
....
```

Expected output are new column which are tags in boolean format. 1 if they have above market return , and 0 if they underperform the market.

```
ticker_name    return   above_market
"AAPL 2020"    -15%        1
"AAPL 2019"     20%        1
"AAPL 2018"     40%        1
"AAPL 2017"     30%        1
"AAPL 2016"    -10%        0
....
```

I found a similar question to mine, however this question is comparing strings and only have two possible input (BULL & BEAR) while mine is float and vary (index return).

[Pandas: if row in column A contains "x", write "y" to row in column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953299/pandas-if-row-in-column-a-contains-x-write-y-to-row-in-column-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would suggest splitting your `ticker_name` column into two columns.

Below `df_ticker` stores your first DataFrame with the stock ticker, year and return. Here the `Series.str.split()` method is used to split the ticker from the year, then we used the trick described here [Python pandas split column list into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58366330/python-pandas-split-column-list-into-multiple-columns).

```py
df_ticker = df_ticker.join(pd.DataFrame(df_ticker['ticker_name'].str.split().tolist(), columns=['ticker', 'year']))
```

Two new columns are created :

```
    ticker_name return  ticker  year
0   AAPL 2020   -0.15   AAPL    2020
1   AAPL 2019   0.20    AAPL    2019
2   AAPL 2018   0.40    AAPL    2018
3   AAPL 2017   0.30    AAPL    2017
4   AAPL 2016   -0.10   AAPL    2016
```

Then I would suggest setting the year as the index, this will ease comparisons between DataFrames.

```py
df_ticker = df_ticker.set_index('year')
```

Grants:

```
    ticker_name return  ticker
year            
2020    AAPL 2020   -0.15   AAPL
2019    AAPL 2019   0.20    AAPL
2018    AAPL 2018   0.40    AAPL
2017    AAPL 2017   0.30    AAPL
2016    AAPL 2016   -0.10   AAPL
```

And

```py
df_index = df_index.set_index('sp_500_year')
```

Grants

```
    return
sp_500_year 
2020    -0.3
2019    0.1
2018    0.1
2017    0.1
2016    0.2
```

Now you can safely compare both DataFrames

```py
df_ticker['above_index'] = df_ticker['return'] > df_index['return']
```

```
    ticker_name return  ticker  above_index
year                
2020    AAPL 2020   -0.15   AAPL    True
2019    AAPL 2019   0.20    AAPL    True
2018    AAPL 2018   0.40    AAPL    True
2017    AAPL 2017   0.30    AAPL    True
2016    AAPL 2016   -0.10   AAPL    False
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. appreciate it @arhr.