# List of dictionaries with multiple values per key as Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a list of dictionaries with multiple values per key to a Dataframe.

```
d = [
    {'2020-12-31 00:00:00': [123, 456, 789, 321]}, 
    {'2021-05-06 00:00:00': [999, 888, 777, 666]}
]
```

The Dataframe should look like this:

| index | Date | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-12-31 00:00:00 | 123 | 456 | 789 | 321 |
| 1 | 2021-05-06 00:00:00 | 999 | 888 | 777 | 666 |

I know that creating a Dataframe with a list of dictionaries is easily achievable with `pd.DataFrame(dictionaries)` but i would like to split the values into separate columns.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(d).stack().apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('Value_')` ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663903/pandas-split-column-of-lists-of-unequal-length-into-multiple-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(d).stack().apply(
    pd.Series).add_prefix(
    'Value').reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'index', 'level_1':'Date'})
```

**Output**

```
    index Date               Value0 Value1  Value2  Value3
0   0     2020-12-31 00:00:00   123  456    789     321
1   1     2021-05-06 00:00:00   999  888    777     666
```